# Como puedo renombrar el nombre de un elemento tab en materializecss?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, materialize

Hola gente de Stackoverflow, espero que tengan un gran día. Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y tengo que usar los elementos tabs del framework Materializecss (un framework de material design). Básicamente quiero lograr el siguiente comportamiento en el elemento tab: el usuario debe poder editar el nombre del elemento tab haciendo doble clic en el nombre actual, debe poder editar el nombre cuantas veces quiera dando doble click en el nombre que ya posea. 
En la siguiente imagen se muestra el elemento tab de materialize: 
[image: elemento tab]

En esta imagen, pueden ver que hay dos tabs(tambien llamadas pestañas), bueno, quiero que al hacer doble clic, por ejemplo, en el nombre "NEWFILTER"(nombre de la primera pestaña) se desbloquee o aparezca automáticamente un cuadro de texto con el nombre actual "filtro nuevo" y la posibilidad de borrar ese texto e ingresar un nuevo nombre. Cuando el usuario termine, presione la tecla enter y automáticamente el nuevo nombre debe colocarse como el nombre de la pestaña actual. ¿¿¿Me entienden??? ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso con jquery o javascript? ¿Alguna idea? Aquí está el código del elemento tab de materializecss:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test1">NEWFILTER</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test2">New Tab</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="test1" class="col s12">BODY TAB 1</div>
    <div id="test2" class="col s12">BODY TAB 2</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: hola, ¿quieres como un modal?

Answer (score 1):

> Esto no queda guardado, solo es visual.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnA2").click(function() {
    var txt = document.getElementById('txtA2').value;
    $('#txtT2').replaceWith('<a id="txtT2" class="active" href="#test2">' + txt + '</a>');
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnA1").click(function() {
    var txt = document.getElementById('txtA1').value;
    $('#txtT1').replaceWith('<a id="txtT1" class="active" href="#test1">' + txt + '</a>');
  });
});
```

```html
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_confirmacion.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s3"><a id="txtT1" class="active" href="#test1">NEWFILTER</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a id="txtT2" href="#test2">New Tab</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="test1" class="col s12">
      Cambiar Nombre <input type="text" name="txtA1" id="txtA1" value="" />
      <input class="btn" type="button" value="guardar" id="btnA1" name="btnA1" />
    </div>
    <div id="test2" class="col s12">
      Cambiar Nombre <input type="text" name="txtA2" id="txtA2" value="" />
      <input class="btn" type="button" value="guardar" id="btnA2" name="btnA2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: me gustaria que el nuevo nombre se escribiera directamente en el espacio donde estaba el nombre anterior, o sea darle doble click encima de "NEWFILTER" y que ahi mismo pueda borrar ese nombre y escribir el nuevo nombre, entonces cuando le de enter se guarde el nombre nuevo

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar contenteditable=true para que puedas editar el texto y cuando apretes enter se deberia guardar en tu bd para que la proxima se cargue con ese nombre.

```js
document.getElementById('changeName').addEventListener('keydown', inputCharacters);

function OnFocusTab(element) {
  element.contentEditable = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (document.activeElement !== element) {
      element.contentEditable = false;
    }
  }, 300);
}

function inputCharacters(element) {
  var txt = document.getElementById('name').innerHTML;
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    $('#name').replaceWith('<a id="txtT2" href="#test2">' + txt + '</a>');
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li id='changeName' onclick="OnFocusTab(this);" class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test1"><span id='name'>NEWFILTER</span></a></li>
      <li class="tab col s3"><a id="a2" href="#test2"><span id='name2'>New Tab</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="test1" class="col s12">BODY TAB 1</div>
  <div id="test2" class="col s12">BODY TAB 2</div>
</div>
```

**segun el OP**, tiene que ser al darle doble click al nombre de la tab no un solo click, porque si se le da un click no deberia permitirme editar el nombre, solo cuando le de doble click.

```
element.contentEditable = true; // por defecto ponemos al elemento como editable
      setTimeout(function() { // si pasa 3milisegundos y no esta activado el elemento seteamos con No-editable
        if (document.activeElement !== element) {
          element.contentEditable = false;
        }
      }, 300);
```

Comment: no me funciona porque al darle enter para cambiar el nombre se borra la tab que esta al lado derecho y no quiero eso, no pueden borrarse las tabs, solo renombra el nombre.

Comment: y tiene que ser al darle doble click al nombre de la tab no un solo click, porque si se le da un click no deberia permitirme editar el nombre, solo cuando le de doble click.

Comment: @N.bravoA edite mi respuesta, para que sea editable con doble click

Comment: Me arroja error cuando le doy enter al final. La cuestion es que, si le doy doble click deberia aparecerme para editar el nombre de la tab (eso lo hace, hasta ahi todo bien) y cuando presione la tecla "enter" deberia quedarse el nombre cambiado y la tab debe volverse a bloquear, o sea ya no deberia aparecerme como un campo de texto sino como al prinicipio(eso es lo que no hace.), me entiendes? si le doy doble click se activa el campo editable, cuando presione enter se guarda ese nombre y el campo de edicion debe quitarse.

Answer (score 0):

hola lo que tu necesitas usar un lenguaje de programacion en el servidor , si estas en local (servidor local:xampp,lampp,wampp), puedes usar PHP para crear un pequeño crud para editar informacion de elemento.

aqui tienes una pequeña informacion acerca de los CRUD que te puede ayudar : 
[CRUD](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/modifying-data-with-sql/adding-data-to-a-database/introduction-to-crud)

si usas Jquery,JavaScript la informacion solamente se almacenaria literalmente en el cliente(navegador) y si recargas de nuevo el navegador los datos volverias a su estado default.

Programación web: lenguajes del lado servidor y del lado cliente
La web funciona según un principio realmente sencillo: los servidores web albergan los contenidos y los clientes los solicitan por HTTP o FTP, entendiendo por clientes a los navegadores (Mozilla Firefox o Google Chrome) instalados en el sistema del usuario, donde se ejecutan. Por el contrario, los servidores web, como Apache o NGINX, forman parte de los proyectos de desarrollo web, se instalan y se ejecutan en este entorno y permiten a los clientes el acceso a los contenidos.

Los contenidos estáticos, como los clásicos elementos de HTML o las imágenes, sencillamente se envían al navegador y allí se visualizan, los contenidos dinámicos, como una Wiki, un menú desplegable o cualquier tipo de aplicación web solo funcionan por medio de scripts, los cuales se han de ejecutar e interpretar con el lenguaje de programación web correspondiente en el lado del servidor o en el lado del cliente. Es por esto que se diferencia fundamentalmente entre los lenguajes de programación del lado servidor y los lenguajes del lado cliente.

Comment: si, ese nuevo nombre debe guardarse en la base de datos; esas tabs van a formar parte de unos formulariso, de hecho en cada tab estara un formulario. E